# Why does my table take so long to load

Tags: php, mysql, google-places-api

I have a site that is going to show businesses near the user. It uses Google APIs to do this. It first grabs nearby businesses using the radar search, grabs the place_id and saves it into the database(which I will need later) and then uses the place ID to grab details about the place. If certain criteria is met, then it displays the results in a table. However, it is taking a long time to load and I am trying to figure out why. If it is just too much information and that's the way it has to be then fine, but I feel like I am doing something inside the code to slow it down more than it should.

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/xml?location=39.53,-89.33&radius=10000&type=establishment&key=MYKEY") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
foreach($xml->result as $get)
{
if($i==7) break;
$xml2 = simplexml_load_file("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/xml?placeid=" . $get->place_id . "&key=MYKEY") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Places WHERE GoogleID = '".$get->place_id."'";
$records = $conn->query($sql);
$grab = $records->fetch_assoc();
if($records->num_rows > 0)
{
    //yay
}
Else
{
    $MakeNew = "INSERT INTO Places (GoogleID, ConfirmedHiring) VALUES ('".$get->place_id."', 'No')";
    if(mysqli_query($conn, $MakeNew))
    {
        $records = $conn->query($sql);
        $grab = $records->fetch_assoc();
    }
}
foreach($xml2->result->address_component as $item){if($item->type == "locality"){$placecity = $item->long_name;}}
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td data-title='Business'>" . $xml2->result->name . "</td>";  
echo "<td data-title='Location'>" . $placecity . "</td>";
echo "<td data-title='Confirmed Hiring'>" .$grab["ConfirmedHiring"]. "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
$i++;
}
?>
```

Comment: How many rows is it pulling out?

Comment: I use an I variable and when I=7, it stops. So 7.

Comment: well yeah you have a `break`

Comment: I only want 7 results to come back, and they do. It just takes a good 5-10 seconds for the page to load, and I feel like I did something wrong in the code to cause that.

Comment: well profile it by putting stopwatch calls for time and echo them in certain parts. For instance, as far as we know, the `simplexml_load_file` could be taking 6 seconds to finish. `Microtime` with a difference output, like line 25 here on github https://gist.github.com/phybros/5766062

Comment: Nothing in the code itself is causing a a delay, there are a couple of points that it could have a slow down though.  The first, is loading in the XML from google, and the second is the query on the database. If the database has a lot of records, and the fields aren't indexed, the query _could_ take a long time to complete. My guess, as Drew said, is that its the call from google thats taking the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you used a nearby search instead of a radar search, you wouldn't have to get the place details separately afterwards, the results would contain all of the details already. If that's not an option and you need to do radar search, you could at least do all of the details requests in parallel.

Similarly, you could select all of the matching records from the DB using an `IN` query instead of selecting them one at a time, and you could insert all of the ones that are found to be missing with a single query as well.

Finally, if something is slow, use a profiler to find out why it's slow; it's faster and more reliable than asking the internet.

Answer (score 1):

1. Avoid doing db insertion / select . because 7 (+7) queries might trigger, you can reduce this to two queries.

```
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/xml?location=39.53,-89.33&radius=10000&type=establishment&key=MYKEY") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
    $places[] = array();
    foreach($xml->result as $get)
    {
        if($i==7) break;
        $xml2 = simplexml_load_file("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/xml?placeid=" . $get->place_id . "&key=MYKEY") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
        $places[] = $get->place_id;
        foreach($xml2->result->address_component as $item){if($item->type == "locality"){$placecity =     $item->long_name;}}
            echo "";
            echo "" . $xml2->result->name . "";  
            echo "" . $placecity . "";
            echo "" .$grab["ConfirmedHiring"]. "";
            echo "";
            $i++;
        }
        if (count($places)) {
            $place_ids = implode(",", $places)
            $sql = "SELECT $place_id FROM Places WHERE GoogleID IN ($place_ids)";
            $records = $conn->query($sql);
            $grab = $records->fetch_array();
            if (count($grab)) {
                $new_place_ids = array_diff($place_ids, $grab)
            } else {
                $new_place_ids = $place_ids;
        }
        $sql_values = "";
        foreach ($new_place_ids as $index => $place_id)
        {
            if (!$sql_values) $sql_values .= ","
            $sql_values .= ('".$get->place_id."', 'No')
        } 
        if ($sql_values != "") {
            $MakeNew = "INSERT INTO Places (GoogleID, ConfirmedHiring) VALUES $sql_values";
            if(mysqli_query($conn, $MakeNew))
            {
                $records = $conn->query($sql);
                $grab = $records->fetch_assoc();
            }
        }
    }
```

2. Store the xml response into a file and cache it for 24 hrs in server. so you avoid further hits. Before hitting the Google, you can check whether the file exist and if it is not older than 24 hrs. 
   instead of the below

```
     $xml2 = simplexml_load_file("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/xml?placeid=" . $get->place_id . "&key=MYKEY") 
//do this 
    $contents= get_content("uploadfolder/".$get->place_id, "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/xml?placeid=" . $get->place_id . "&key=MYKEY");
```

Ref - how to to this for get_content function definition at https://davidwalsh.name/php-cache-function